# Sitecore ContentSearchManager can't find index

Tags: sitecore

I am using Sitecore 7.5 and I try to get bucket item's children.
I have an index "xyz" and it works when I try to get this index using:

```
var context = SearchManager.GetIndex("xyz").CreateSearchContext();
```

But I wanted to use this:

```
using (var context = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("xyz").CreateSearchContext())
{
    IQueryable<SearchResult> results = context.GetQueryable<SearchResult>();
}
```

and I receive an exception "Index xyz was not found". Why SearchManager finds this index but ContentSearchManager does not?

This is my index:

```
<configuration>
  <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
<index id="xyz" type="Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
      <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
      <param desc="folder">xyz</param>
      <Analyzer ref="search/analyzer" />
      <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <web-pomoc type="Website.Classes.Search.BasicDatabaseCrawler, Website">
          <Database>web</Database>
          <Root>/sitecore/content/Shared/Kolekcje/Vod/Catchup-VOD</Root>
          <templates hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
            <entry>{DA757C92-A4CC-468F-BC22-AD347C8C4C9C}</entry>
          </templates>
        </web-pomoc>
      </locat
  </indexes>
</configuration>
```

**Edit**:
I changed my index and now it looks like this:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
        <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
          <index id="catchup_search" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
            <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration type=”Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndexConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider”>
            <indexAllFields>false</indexAllFields>
            <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
            <analyzer ref=”contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration/analyzer” />
            <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
                <catchup_entry>{DA757C92-A4CC-468F-BC22-AD347C8C4C9C}</catchup_entry>
            </include>
        </configuration>
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/xyz/avc</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
          </index>
        </indexes>
      </configuration>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Now it appears in Index manager, but when I rebuild it, 0 items is processed.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type from **Sitecore.Search.Index, Sitecore.Kernel** to **Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider**

SearchManager.GetIndex("xyz").CreateSearchContext() - makes use of the IndexSearchContext

while

ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("xyz").CreateSearchContext() - makes use of SitecoreContentSearch

Sitecore make use of the SitecoreContentSearch to rebuild the indexes.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your index definition is wrong
You need to use something like:

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
 <sitecore>
  <contentSearch>
  <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ContentSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
    <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
      <index id="sitecore_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
         ...
      </index>
    </indexes>
  </configuration>
</contentSearch>
```

Please check default index definition from Sitecore 7.5

After you add index configuration file please check if your index appear in IndexManager:

[image]

Comment: /sitecore/content/xyz/avc do you have this Item in web database?

Comment: Can you also check if you have items with id: {DA757C92-A4CC-468F-BC22-AD347C8C4C9C} under the root   
/sitecore/content/xyz/avc on web database

Comment: Yes, /sitecore/content/xyz/avc is a bucket items and it contains item with this templateID

Comment: Maybe I have to configure fieldMap?

Comment: When I change to "defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration" it works fine